# Dispatch admin_system_config_changed_section_XXX externally

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Is it possible to dispatch the event admin_system_config_changed_section_XXX, for which I have an observer in my custom extension, from an external shell or PHP script?

Comment: what's an outside script?

Comment: Sorry, I meant an external PHP script.